# VPN stops after short time

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to connect by VPN to my work. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I can connect by VPN, and then I can connect by ssh to a server in my institution. I can work by no longer than 2-3 minutes. After this time, ssh connection stop, despite VPN connection is still active (icon is on a bar). I checked, that everything is fine on the ssh server site.

Before VPN conection

```
$ sudo iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Oct 25 13:06:59 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [120670:85653701]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83638:10700404]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 25 13:06:59 2018
```

After VPN connection

```
$ sudo iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Oct 25 13:07:09 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [120921:85684980]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83845:10723312]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 25 13:07:09 2018
```

After problem with connection

```
$ sudo iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu Oct 25 13:09:06 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [122601:86062241]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [85362:10900233]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 25 13:09:06 2018
```

Do you have any suggestion?